# Why is CSS transition not working upon clicking menu button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

**Whenever I click upon the menu, a class 'active' gets added to the 'div' and the 'section' as shown.**

[image]

The javascript code used to do the above mentioned is

```
<script>
    const menuToggle = document.querySelector('.toggle')
    const frontpage = document.querySelector('.front-page')

    menuToggle.addEventListener('click', () =>{
      menuToggle.classList.toggle('active')
      frontpage.classList.toggle('active')
    }) 
</script>
```

The CSS for the class front-page and toggle are as shown

[image]

So the page moves to the right but no transition takes place as shown

[image]

I am a noob , so please kindly tell me why is this transition not working

Index File: https://github.com/rajas2716/rajas2716.github.io/blob/master/index.html

CSS File: https://github.com/rajas2716/rajas2716.github.io/blob/master/css/styles.css

Github link to project:  https://github.com/rajas2716/rajas2716.github.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `right` value of `0` to the default state in the `.front-page` rule (i.e. a value from which the transition starts), and you need to write "all"  or "right"  into the `transition` setting, like `transition: all 0.5s`.